# Why do I have to power cycle my wireless flash controller when using a YN560 IV?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

I have Nikon D750 and just recently bought 3 yn560iv and yn controller tx. I was able to set them up and they all fire, but the flashes only fires once. In order for them to fire again I have to change power up or down on the controller and then it will fire one time again.

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3900595

Comment: What debugging/troubleshooting have you tried? AFAIK, this gear combination should work.

Comment: My initial thought would be that your YN560-TX is faulty and I would begin by investigating that possibility.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've got this issue with my Fuji XE-3 and it's driving me mad!! I've got two YN560-TX and same issue with both